# how to plot overlay multiple time series given condition(s) in lattice?

Tags: r, time-series, lattice

Suppose I have a data frame, df,  that looks like:

```
f t1 t2 t3
h 1  3  4
h 2  4  3
t 3  4  5
t 5  6  8
```

with f being a factor and $t attributes being numerical values related to time ordered events.
I could overlay time series t1 to t3 using par(new=T) and isolate by factor manually.
But I wonder if there is some way to do this with lattice, where the overlaid time series
are conditioned by the factor. So we would have two panels, with overlaid time series corresponding to conditional factors, f. Most examples I've seen only use one time series (vector) per factor. I also thought about using a parallel plot, but time information is lost.
I've also tried something like

```
xyplot(df$t1+df$t2+df$t3 ~seq(3) | factor(df$f))
```

, but it loses row sequence connections.  Anyone know if this is possible?

Here's a very crude illustration using non lattice approach.

```
x<-matrix(seq(12),4,3)
f<-c('a','a','b','b')
df<-data.frame(f,x)

layout(1:2); yr<-c(0,12); xr<-c(1,3);
plot(as.numeric(df[1,2:4])~seq(3),type='o',ylim=yr,xlim=xr,ylab='A')
par(new=T)
plot(as.numeric(df[2,2:4])~seq(3),type='o',ylim=yr,xlim=xr,ylab='A')

plot(as.numeric(df[3,2:4])~seq(3), type='o',ylim=yr,xlim=xr,ylab='B')
par(new=T)
plot(as.numeric(df[4,2:4])~seq(3),type='o',ylim=yr,xlim=xr,ylab='B')
```

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions. I had thought about using some kind of melt or cast approach, but didn't think it through. @Dwin  Seems like a perfectly elegant solution to what I was looking for, I'm hoping it can handle large data sets fairly fast and well. Thanks again, all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an ID variable and melted with package:reshape2

```
 dat
  f t1 t2 t3 ID
1 h  1  3  4  1
2 h  2  4  3  2
3 t  3  4  5  3
4 t  5  6  8  4
datm <- melt(dat, id.vars=c("ID","f"), measure.vars=c("t1", "t2", "t3"))
> datm
   ID f variable value
1   1 h       t1     1
2   2 h       t1     2
3   3 t       t1     3
4   4 t       t1     5
5   1 h       t2     3
6   2 h       t2     4
7   3 t       t2     4
8   4 t       t2     6
9   1 h       t3     4
10  2 h       t3     3
11  3 t       t3     5
12  4 t       t3     8
```

Since you asked to have it "overlayed" I used the group parameter to keep the ID's separate and the "|" operator to give you the two panels for "h" and "t":

```
xyplot(value~variable|f, group=ID, data=datm, type="b")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(1) This can be done compactly using `xyplot.zoo` .  The first statement converts the data frame to a zoo series (series are stored in columns in zoo objects) and the second statement plots it such that the screen argument defines which panel each series is shown in:

```
library(zoo)
library(lattice)

z <- zoo(t(df[-1]))

xyplot(z, screen = df$f, type = "o")
```

(2) or if it were desired to show `df`'s column names on the X axis instead then define `z` as the following (and then issue the `xyplot` command above):

```
z <- zoo(t(df[-1])), factor(names(df[-1])))
```

`xyplot` using the `z` in the first point looks like this (and the second is the same except for the X axis labels):

[image: xyplot.zoo output]

EDIT: simplified (2)